# Letters and Numbers Have Different Font Sizes in Subscript

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I observe that number subscripts are having bigger font sizes than letter subscript.
Here is my **MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$Y_t=X_1,X_2\cdots X_p$
\end{document}
```

Please run it to see the difference.
What can I do to make both look the same font size?

Comment: If you replace `X_p` with for example `X_b`, you will easy to see, that they have the same size. Visually `p` may looks smaller, but it is not.

Comment: I mean numbers are bigger than letters. If you doubt it, print it on paper to see the difference

Comment: Digits are essentially the same size as uppercase letters.  If you set `X_N`, that would be obvious.

Comment: Add \showoutput to your file then you see what is put on the page and you will see that everything in the subscripts is typeset in the same font size. Of course, how tall glyphs are depend on their design and that can differ from font to font.